# Can you create an express api for an existing domain?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

Let's say I have a domain already running called http://docs.domain.com.

This isn't an express server it's something I don't have control over, however I do have full control over the source files, so I was hoping there's I way with ExpressJs that I can sort of reverse proxy a restful app?

So http://docs.domain.com/app/products and that would get data locally?

Or is there something else I can do with node to save a file locally from the website?

Comment: Assuming that by _source files_ you mean the HTML/JS/CSS for that site: that's not going to be enough. You need to be able to modify the HTTP server configuration.

Comment: I have access to command line, and full control over the directory, which means I can use node and express

Comment: If you can't change the HTTP server configuration, an option would be to run Node on another port. It depends on the actual use case (is it your intention to call the REST service from your own frontend?) it that's a suitable solution.

Comment: Would I have issues with cross origin though creating the rest api with node?

Comment: Yes, but those can be fixed by enabling CORS support in your Express server (using the [`cors`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware, for instance).

Comment: Okay great thanks mate I'll give it a shot!